# Spark SQL doesn't support Chinese column name in sql query

Tags: apache-spark

I am running the following spark sql:

```
  test("SparkSQLTest") {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master(s"local[1]").config("spark.sql.cbo.enabled", true).appName("SparkSQLTest").getOrCreate()
    spark.createDataFrame(Seq(Person("Tom", 31), Person("Jack", 22))).createOrReplaceTempView("t")
    val df = spark.sql("select name, '' XYZ, '' 水果,  age from t ")
    df.show(false)
  }
```

I add a constant, name it to `水果`， but Spark SQL doesn't recognize it

Answer (score 0):

While creating the spark session object set the encoding option as SJIS. It’s a character encoding

Comment: Thanks @chandan, I didn't find how to specify the encoding, could you please show some demo code? Thanks!

Comment: While creation spark session instance please try .option(“charset”, “SJIS”)

Comment: Thanks @chandan. I didn't find the option method. Instead, I am using config method as follows: 
`val spark=SparkSession.builder().config(charset,SJIS).m∗er(local).appName(SparkSQLTest).getOrCreate`

Comment: Did it work please check and let me know as we need to play with those charset

Comment: Let me try in my system. Will keep you posted

Comment: it gives me a warning stating "Warning: Ignoring non-spark config property: charset=SJIS" and does not have any effect